# Appending an Operator at the end of a Grep Command to Set as Bash Variable

Tags: bash, alias

I am needing to append an addition operator at the end of the command that parses out the IP address from a list of running VM's in our labs. The command is as follows

```
$ dos.py net-list vanilla80 | grep -i 'fuelweb' | grep -Eo "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].([0-9])"
```

At the end I would like to add two to the last number in the IP address at the end of the IP address.

Example 171.11.111.0 => 172.11.111.2

Any suggestions to this issue??? I am trying to make our labs more efficient with alias commands that reference a script that will match running lab vms and push their keys to allow for easy access to vanilla provisioned labs.

Comment: `awk -F . '{$NF+=1}1'` ... and use shell functions or scripts instead of aliases.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: So I tried it and it takes out the periods because it is using the period as the field separator. As I am writing this into my script, I need the periods so I can ssh into the vms. Anyway to not have the periods taken out but still use the expression?

Comment: Current Command: dos.py net-list vanilla80 | grep -i 'fuelweb' | grep -Eo "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].([0-9])" | awk -F . '{$NF+=2}1'

Comment: Oh sorry, you need to add `BEGIN { OFS=FS }` immediately after the opening quote.

Comment: Okay, let me try it

Comment: Quick and dirty; the entire pipeline should probably be refactored to a single Awk script (or Python, for that matter) but we need to know more about the expected output from `dos.py`.

Comment: Final command: dos.py net-list vanilla80 | grep -i 'fuelweb' | grep -Eo "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].([0-9])" | awk -F . 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}{$NF+=2}1'

Comment: Okay so I have an issue with the command, it is not really accounting for the IP addresses properly because it is accounting for a number in the grep -Eo output

Comment: For example, I am trying to grep and then account for the IP with awk by the following format [0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't understand what's not working. Your regex is kind of careless, though; maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It's not clear what should happen if the last octet in the IP address is 253 or larger, by the way. Perhaps this won't be happening in practice...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick and dirty answer,

```
dos.py net-list vanilla80 |
grep -i 'fuelweb' |
grep -Eo "[0-9][0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].([0-9])" |
awk -F . 'BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    { $NF += 2 }1'
```

However, a much better solution would be to refactor `dos.py` to produce machine-readable output, and/or perhaps turn it into a module you can `import` from another Python script which would replace this shell pipeline.

As an aside, your `grep -Eo` regex could be refactored into something like `\<[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})(3}\>` and if you don't end up rewriting all of this logic in Python, perhaps the entire pipeline could be refactored into a single Awk script.

Comment: Cool thanks, I actually created a script to run and do the following and  grab the names and the Ip addresses dynamically. Works better.

Comment: Than I set it as a cron job every five minutes for every lab environment running on our servers.